# javascript regular expression - find numbers and spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find all nexus versions. 7 and 7 2 and 10.
I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/8eJQb/

```
function pr(res) {
    document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 4) +
        '</pre><br>')
}

var test = /((Nexus\s[0-9]))/i

var res = test.exec("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.3; Nexus 7 Build/JSS15Q)");
pr(res);//working

var res = test.exec("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.3; Nexus 7 2 Build/JSS15Q)");
pr(res);//not working

var res = test.exec("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.3; Nexus 10 Build/JSS15Q)");
pr(res);//not working
```

how can I change the reg exp /((Nexus\s[0-9]))/i so it will match all the use cases?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't strict the pattern to exactly 1 space and exactly 1 number (the number 10 will example won't be catched)

use `var test = /Nexus\s+([0-9][0-9\s]*)+/i` instead

See this fiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/8eJQb/6/

Explanation:

the first `\s+` - means that after the 'Nexus' word we must have at least one space

the `[0-9][0-9\s]*` means that we must have at least one digit after the spaces - and then any number of digits and spaces are welcome - it is wrapped with `()` so we can use it later

Comment: Thanks, how can I swap places in the results? 10 becomes first and Nexus 10 becomes second. you answer is actually good, but I cant use it since I am submitting it to a framework that needs the result the apposite way. thanks

Comment: you can't - the first result is always the full match - but, you can swap them manually before sending - like in : http://jsfiddle.net/8eJQb/12/

Answer (score 1):

If all you ever need is those three version you have mentioned, you can use a more specific regexp:

```
var test = /Nexus\s(?:7(?:\s2)?|10)/i
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8eJQb/9/

Otherwise, just add more than one digit, followed by optional group of space and one digit:

```
var test = /Nexus\s[0-9]+(?:\s[0-9])?/i
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8eJQb/7/

Answer (score 1):

The following should work for you.

```
var test = /Nexus\s*(?:7(?: 2)?|10)/i
```

Perhaps in this case a Negative Lookahead may suffice also.

```
var test = /Nexus\s*(?:(?!Build).)+(?=\s)/i
```